# Let's find some contradictions!

Tags: discussion, challenge

It's been a long time since I proposed a weekly challenge:

I think a lot of people are interested in how to resolve apparent textual discrepancies or contradictions.  In fact, several people have expressed interest in seeing how this site handles those sorts of questions.  I've gone through some of the questions on the site and added [contradiction](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction) to those that seem to be asking about how one Biblical text might say the opposite of some other text.  We have a number of good solutions to those potential problems in the answers.

For this upcoming week, I'd like to challenge us all to find and ask about common "contradictions" in the Bible.  There's a lot of low-hanging fruit out there and it has the potential to draw people to the site.  As always, the only "prize" is the satisfaction of knowing you helped make the internet a better place to find answers to questions about the Bible.

Answer (score 4):

Great idea, Jon -- on a number of levels! I appreciate your involvement on this site and your interest in making it even more accessible to random Googlers. This particular thread of questions is right on-target.

I have one small suggestion, however: I think you might want to consider renaming the tag. Interestingly, I posted a question about an apparent contradiction this very week (without even knowing about your weekly challenge!) I searched for an appropriate tag name but didn't find one, so I created my own ("Contradiction"). I agree that "textual-discrepancies" is more precise, but I'm afraid any future posters would never think to search for that one (I certainly never would have) -- so it will end up only being used by people familiar with this challenge. You yourself used "contradictions" in the title of this post (as well as in your description), which I think just goes to show that it is the more commonly used word for this sort of thing. (I was actually surprised to find that it wasn't already a tag!)

What would you think about going through all the questions that you submitted and re-tagging them?

Comment: See also: http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/294/68 ;-)

Comment: I suggested a synonym that might help: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags/textual-discrepancies/synonyms

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is a great idea, because a person who actually finds a contradiction in the text (I can immediately think of a few dozen just in Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus), will ask a better question about it, with more detail, than somebody responding to your challenge. Nevertheless, I can ask some interesting ones relating to contradictions that nobody notices.